# Flex app installed on my android phone, does not create a shortcut icon

Tags: android, apache-flex, icons, shortcut

Apk file from Flex to make the Android phones have been installed.

Shortcut icon does not appear on the screen.

What should I do?

Comment: I've never installed an app on an Android device that automatically added an icon on the home screen.  I always have to explicitly add it to the home screen ffrom the list of all apps.  Usually a "click and hold" on the app icon will close the list of all apps and bring up the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

First check if in Playstore setting if auto add widgets is checked or not. 
Second mark automatically add home screen shortcuts checkbox in home screen launcher settings.

Third installing app on different device and check if you are getting shortcut or not.

Comment: There is no setting while uploading apk to playstore. Settings can only be configured after successful publish on playstore.